# How to call service method from html file?

Tags: angular

Lets explain my code, I am having one component file and one service file

First, From the component I am passing the values to the service file's methods and storing the values as global variable in service file.

Second, I am calling another one method in the component file, and I am trying to access the global variable, what I stored earlier.

My code is below

Component file

```
import { NewService } from './new.service';



@Component({
selector: 'test',
templateUrl: './passwordPolicy.html',
providers: [FormErrorService]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    obj1 = {"val":1,"val2":2};
    obj2 = {"val":1,"val2":2};

    constructor(private ns: NewService,) {

    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.ns.firstMethod(this.obj1,this.obj1);
    }

    keyCheck(){
        this.ns.secondMethod();
    }

}
```

Service file

```
export class NewService{
    Sobj: any;
    Sobj2: any;
    firstMethod(v1,v2){
        this.Sobj = v1;
        this.Sobj2 = v2;        
    }
    secondMethod(){
        console.log(this.Sobj);
        console.log(this.Sobj2);
    }
}
```

and the template file

```
<button (click)='keycheck()'>Enter</button>
```

When clicking the button I am getting console.log with the values.

---

Now my question is I am trying to the call the service method from the Html file, like as follow

component file

```
    sMet:any;
    constructor(private ns: NewService,) {
        this.sMet = this.ns.secondMethod;
    }
```

And the html file is

```
<button (click)='sMet()'>Enter</button>
```

but above code is giving service's object are undefined. How to call it.?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxtfty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You seem to have a typo in `firstMethod(v1,v3){` shouldn't it be `v2`?

Comment: Your demo shows the first method works. Why don't you use it instead of the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not use anything like `sMet()`

Directly use

```
<button (click)='ns.secondMethod()'>Enter</button>
```

refer the code at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ig5pa)

If you want to use some variable, then use in the below way,

```
sMet = () => this.ns.secondMethod();
```

And  in html,

```
<button (click)='sMet()'>Enter</button>
```

If you want to use the same way as described in your demo stackblitz, make the `secondMethod()` in your testService as an arrow function like below.

```
   secondMethod = () => {
        console.log(this.Sobj);
        console.log(this.Sobj2);
    }
```

here is your edited [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkhwmz?file=src/app/testService.ts) code

Comment: Please look at the stackblitz. There are some mistakes in your code which might have appeared when you post the code. I corrected them

Comment: Initialise the sevice like this `ns = new NewService();`

Comment: This is working. Can you explain why it is not working with declaring the method in variable and accessing it.?

Comment: I tried declaring the variable at last in `ngOnInit` but that time also this is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188537/discussion-between-dileepkumar-jami-and-mkhun).

Answer (score 17):

declare the service as public in the component constructor

```
constructor(public ns: NewService) { }
```

then you can use it directly in HTML

```
<button (click)="ns.secondMethod()">button</button>
```

Comment: Just what i wanted, thanks. wondering if its bad to make it public, but its less code then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
sMet() {
  this.ns.secondMethod();
}

constructor(private ns: NewService) {}
```

Basically, instead of assigning the service method you wrap it with a component method.

Comment: In your question you assign it... `this.sMet = this.ns.secondMethod;` Calling the component method from the HTML looks fine.

Comment: Please see the first part of my question, I am calling the `keycheck` method from that I am calling the service method.

Comment: OK. I'm obviously missing something. If you have the first part working, why do you try to do it differently on the second part?

Comment: I am trying to call the method from the HTML file, the service's file method is calling, but the problem is assigned variable of `sObj` and `sObj1` getting undefined. If I am calling the service's file method from the component it it has the data.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly the problem. Can you try and create a [mcve]? You can do it online: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Answer (score 0):

first of all inject the service in constructor of component

```
constructor(public newService: NewService) { }
```

for access the global variable

```
<button (click)="newService.sobj">
```

for access the methods of services:

```
<button (click)="newService.firstMethod(v1,v2)">
```

best Regards!